# 5 seconds Timer in VHDL

Tags: timer, vhdl, counter, intel-fpga

I am using 50MHz clock in fpga and trying make 5 seconds timer. below cnt_t reach to 5 x 50MHz (x"0EE6B280" --> 250,000,000) then make time_tick_32 to 1 and make cnt_t <= x"00000000";. The code below did not work never time_tick_32 gets 1.

```
signal cnt_t    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0) := x"00000000";
signal time_tick : STD_LOGIC:= '0' ;
signal time_tick_32 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0):= x"00000000";


process (clk_50) IS
    begin
      if falling_edge(clk_50)  then
      cnt_t <= cnt_t + '1';
      end if;
    if (cnt_t = x"0EE6B280") then --if 5 seconds  
        time_tick <= '1';
        cnt_t <= x"00000000";
        time_tick_32(0)<=time_tick;
    else
        time_tick <= '0';
        time_tick_32(0)<=time_tick;
    end if;

end process;
```

Comment: Not sure about this language, but are you sure you want your numbers to be compared with strings inside condition?

Comment: @Gogol `x"...."` is a hexadecimal bitstring literal. So it's not a comparison with a (character) string.

Comment: Please show us the complete code. Here are some hints: 1. change the type of `cnt_t` to `unsigned` or `natural`. 2. you don't need 32 bits. 3. Don't use magic numbers => use integer values. (Type unsigned can be compared with integer.)

Comment: @Paebbels you're right about the magic number. But an integer is usually still considered a magic number (not that it is a problem.) Fixing magic numbers is to define a constant called "five_second_in_50MHz" or so and test for that constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
signal cnt_t    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0) := x"00000000";
signal time_tick : STD_LOGIC:= '0' ;
signal time_tick_32 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0):= x"00000000";


-- I assume you begin your architecture somewhere
-- Can make the following a concurrent statement
-- (unless it is some kind of shift reg assigned in a diff process...
-- then you will get multiple driver issues)
time_tick_32(0) <= time_tick;

process (clk_50) IS
begin
    if rising_edge(clk_50)  then -- Changed to rising_edge; 
                                -- Any particular reason you are using falling_edge?
        if (cnt_t = x"0EE6B280") then --if 5 seconds  
            time_tick <= '1';
            cnt_t <= x"00000000";
        else
            time_tick <= '0';
            cnt_t <= cnt_t + '1';  
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: You can assign a signal outside of a process (within the architecture block), which will consitute a _concurrent_ assignment. It is hard to determine what you are using `time_tick_32` for; As long as you aren't assigning to it somewhere else you should be fine